# Getting the error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: exception, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError error when I try to run my code on 32-bit machine.
I have exactly same code on 64-bit machine. This works fine without any issues.
I have looked at all the symbols in my binaries, I have checked the library paths, etc.
I didn't find any issues with any of them.
Can you please check this and let me know how to proceed.

The error log is presented below.

Regards,
Narendra

```
Exception in thread "Data Adapter" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.abc.iot.analytics.auto.adapter.usb.DATAReader.getMYchannelsJNI()V
    at com.abc.iot.analytics.auto.adapter.usb.DATAReader.MychannelsJNI(Native Method)
    at com.abc.iot.analytics.auto.adapter.usb.MyAdapter.getMyChannels(MyAdapter.java:19)
    at com.abc.iot.analytics.auto.adapter.usb.MyAdapter.readData(MyAdapter.java:34)
    at iot.analytics.auto.adapter.AbstractDataAdapter.run(AbstractDataAdapter.java:42)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Does the 32-bit JVM find the library? Is `getMYchannelsJNI()` the first native method you use, or some other method was successfully called before?

Comment: getMYchannelsJNI() is the first native method that gets called.
It's able to find the library. I validated this by moving the library to some other location and it gave error that the library is not found.

Comment: Which toolchain(s) do you use? Which OS is running?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 32-bit.
I tried the same on Windows 7 64-bit and it worked fine.
I used MINGW to compile the C code and jdk1.8.0_102 for compiling Java and executing the java executable.

Comment: Try loading the native library explicitly using System.loadLibrary("mylib");
 and see if it is succeeding.  If not, the library is not loading and you should run "depends" tool to check the .dll for missing dependencies.